# How random option catch correspondent number?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$("#question2").hide();
const options = [$(".option1"), $(".option2"), $(".option3"), $(".option4")];

let randomOption = function() {
  const texts = options
    .map(opt => opt[0].textContent)
    .sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

  $(".option1").text(texts[0]);
  $(".option2").text(texts[1]);
  $(".option3").text(texts[2]);
  $(".option4").text(texts[3]);
}



$("#question1 button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("correct")) {
    $("#question1").fadeOut();
    $("#question2").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(this).text("X")
  }
})
$("#question2 button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("correct")) {
    $("#question2").fadeOut();
    $("#question1").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(this).text("X")
  }
})

console.log(randomOption())
```

```css
button {
  background-color: rgb(192, 235, 179)
}

.container {
  margin-top: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="question1">question 1
    <button class="option1 correct">1</button>
    <button class="option2">2</button>
    <button class="option3">3</button>
    <button class="option4">4</button>
  </div>
  <div id="question2">question 2
    <button class="option1">1</button>
    <button class="option2 correct">2</button>
    <button class="option3">3</button>
    <button class="option4">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

How random option catch correspondent number ?

For example:

- If question random option is (4) (2) (3) (1) arrangement
- Answer should be (1),because set class="correct" in question1 option1
  but in the case  (1) is X (wrong answer).

I guess it get `<div>` position, so array and real number not match.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you give a better description of the problem and your goal. It's not at all clear.

Comment: i want  class correct get random option number. not <div> position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are fixing `correct` class on theses positions. Add `correct` when generate random values:

```
$('#question1 button:contains("1")').addClass("correct");
$('#question2 button:contains("2")').addClass("correct");
```

---

#### Live example with  dynamic positions:

```js
$("#question2").hide();
const options = [$(".option1"), $(".option2"), $(".option3"), $(".option4")];

let randomOption = function() {
  const texts = options
    .map(opt => opt[0].textContent)
    .sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

  $(".option1").text(texts[0]);
  $(".option2").text(texts[1]);
  $(".option3").text(texts[2]);
  $(".option4").text(texts[3]);

  let correct1 = randomInteger(1, 4);
  let correct2 = randomInteger(1, 4);

  $('#question1 button:contains(' + correct1 + ')').addClass("correct");
  $('#question2 button:contains(' + correct2 + ')').addClass("correct");
}

$("#question1 button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("correct")) {
    $("#question1").fadeOut();
    $("#question2").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(this).text("X")
  }
})
$("#question2 button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("correct")) {
    $("#question2").fadeOut();
    $("#question1").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(this).text("X")
  }
})

function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

console.log(randomOption());
```

```css
button {
  background-color: rgb(192, 235, 179)
}

.container {
  margin-top: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="question1">question 1
    <button class="option1">1</button>
    <button class="option2">2</button>
    <button class="option3">3</button>
    <button class="option4">4</button>
  </div>
  <div id="question2">question 2
    <button class="option1">1</button>
    <button class="option2">2</button>
    <button class="option3">3</button>
    <button class="option4">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Perhaps in addition to dynamic positions for improvement you can also put dynamic responses instead of 1 for question 1 and 2 for question 2:

A simple adjustment can do it:

```
let randomOption = function() {
  const texts = options
    .map(opt => opt[0].textContent)
    .sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

  $(".option1").text(texts[0]);
  $(".option2").text(texts[1]);
  $(".option3").text(texts[2]);
  $(".option4").text(texts[3]);

  let correct1 = randomInteger(1, 4);
  let correct2 = randomInteger(1, 4);

  $('#question1 button:contains(' + correct1 + ')').addClass("correct");
  $('#question2 button:contains(' + correct2 + ')').addClass("correct");
}
```

With simple helper function:

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: @Shawn- Thanks for your feedback. I glad to have helped you.

Comment: I added a sugestion in the end of answer if you want use dynamic responses.